# Dealing with data types in sql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Which data type is recommended to use for a `field` that only stores a `boolean` value (for example status of a user)?

In my case is as following:

```
...
disabled tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
...
```

Is there a performance difference between `tinyint(1)` and `int(11)` ?

Comment: You could use the BIT datatype to represent boolean data in sql server

Comment: Check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about using `bit` since it stores a 0 or 1 aka false or true